# Очистка реестра C++ WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, реестр

Необходимо удалить ключи программ, которые есть в реестре, но которые уже не существуют на жестком диске.
Как решить эту проблему?
Как отслеживать такие ключи?
Буду благодарен любой помощи: объяснениям, коду и **полезным** ссылкам.

Comment: И все-таки: найти или удалить? Это совершенно разные вещи.

Comment: Думаю, что в общем случае можно только найти ключи, которые ссылаются на несуществующие места на диске.

Comment: Для начала именно найти.

Comment: Это я понял. Мне именно нужно понять КАК найти такие ключи.

Comment: разделите задачу ещё дальше - рекурсивный проход по реестру, чтение ключа/значения, проверка существования файла. Но нужно будет ещё научится понимать, является ли значение ключа именем файла. А это может быть весьма неоднозначно.